# google admob ads not shown after replacing the ad units & app id(My Admob account ads) with the TEST (ads & App id)

Tags: java, android, xml

Admob ads not shown in my app when I replace the ads unit & app Id with my own account (admob)

I tried with the both build & singned apk,  no ads were shownand my admob account shows that the ads are REQUESTED but the impression are not shown.

Please help me, how can I handle this problem? I am a new developer.

1. MAIN ACtivity :-

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   Button B1, B2;


   AdView madView;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


       this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);


       MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
       madView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
       AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
       madView.loadAd(adRequest);

       /**B1 to A1*/
       B1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.B1);
       B1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent n1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity1.class);
               startActivity(n1);
           }
       });
       /**B2 to A2*/
       B2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.B2);
       B2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent n2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
               startActivity(n2);
           }
       });


   }
   ```

   }

   2. Activity_main.xml:-

   ```
   <ScrollView
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="600dp"
       android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       tools:ignore="ExtraText">
       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="600dp"
           android:orientation="vertical">

           <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent">

               <Button
                   android:id="@+id/B1"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_margin="8dp"
                   android:background="@color/colorAqua"
                   android:gravity="center"
                   android:padding="10dp"
                   android:textAlignment="center"
                   android:textColor="@color/colorvoilet"
                   android:textSize="17sp"
                   android:textStyle="bold"
                   android:text="@string/q1"/>

           </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

           <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent">

               <Button
                   android:id="@+id/B2"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_margin="8dp"
                   android:background="@color/colorAqua"
                   android:padding="10dp"
                   android:textColor="@color/colorvoilet"
                   android:textAlignment="center"
                   android:gravity="center"
                   android:textSize="17sp"
                   android:textStyle="bold"
                   android:text="@string/q2"/>

           </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


       </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
   <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
       xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:id="@+id/adView"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       ads:adSize="BANNER"
       ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
   </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
   ```

   3. AndroidMAnifest:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> 
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

   <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
       android:supportsRtl="true"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

   <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
           <intent-filter>`enter code here`
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>

   <activity android:name=".Activity1">

   <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
           android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713" />

   </application>

   </manifest>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Add code to manifest file :-

```
<manifest>
<application>
    <!-- Sample AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID"/>
</application>
```

and addTestDevice in java file :

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
.addTestDevice("33BE2250B43518CCDA7DE426D04EE231")  // add your decide ID shown in logcat
.build();
```